# Messenger(FB) app that does not run in background

Tags: battery

On [Windows Phone](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/7482/why-dont-some-apps-have-the-allow-app-to-run-in-the-background-option) and [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html) messaging apps(like Facebook Messenger) simply use push notifications.

Is there an option only to only enable push notifications for FB messenger on Android?

Right now it continues to run in the background draining the battery.

So investigating some more, [Lineage OS displays that background battery usage vs foreground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsjzn.png) implying it is running in the background for notifications.  "Force Stopping" the Android app and notifications stop coming through.  So the answer appears to be no.

Comment: Umm, on Android, [background service is needed to receive push notifications](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) since it's handled per app. That's also why sometimes apps don't receive push notifications since they're killed completely in the background by the system.

Comment: @AndrewT. doesn't that mean the more apps you have installed the greater the battery drain?

Comment: @AndrewT. what is [Google cloud messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) then?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Cloud_Messaging

Comment: @William GCM was the predecessor of FCM, but they are the same service, it became FCM after google acquired firebase. And no the battery drain will not increase if you have more apps because google uses a single connection to handle incoming push notifications, and then simply checks which app the notification is for and passes it on.

Comment: @Tim I can see the app running in the background and its draining battery so I don't believe that is correct.  Check out https://dontkillmyapp.com/

Comment: You are confusing the app running in the background with google maintaining a FCM connection. It's not the same thing.

Comment: @Tim here is a picture on my Motorolla phone.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dQyR.png  Messenger lite is definitely running.

Comment: See my previous message